# blazor custom required validator does not show red border and error message under the field

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, validation, blazor, blazor-webassembly

TL DR: Custom validator doesn't make field border red, and doesn't show validation message. Only shows error messages on ValidationSummary.

We hope to implement a "conditional requirement" validation. When a designated field has value, the requirement will take effect.

The code of the validator is below:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace blazor.Models.Validators
{
public class RequiredWhenOtherHasValue : ValidationAttribute
{
    private readonly string _compareToPropertyName; // if this property has value, require validated property to have a value

    public RequiredWhenOtherHasValue(string compareToPropertyName)
    {
        _compareToPropertyName = compareToPropertyName;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ErrorMessage)) ErrorMessage = "Required";

        var property = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(_compareToPropertyName);

        if (property == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Property with this name not found");

        var compareToObject = property.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance);
        if (compareToObject == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(compareToObject.ToString())) 
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        else if (value == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString()))
            return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }


}
}
```

The validator sort of works, but it only shows on the validation summary. It doesn't give a red border for the validated field, and doesn't show a red error message after the validated field.

Below is a page example, when name1 has value, email1 is required; when name2 has value, email2 is required. But the error message only shows on the summary section.

```
@page "/test"

<EditForm Model="model" Context="formContext">

    <DataAnnotationsValidator></DataAnnotationsValidator>
    <ValidationSummary></ValidationSummary>

    <div class="row w-100">

        <div class="col-12 mb-5">
            Name1:
            <InputText class="form-control" @bind-Value="model.Name1"></InputText>
            <br />
        </div>

        <div class="col-12 mb-5">
            Email1:
            <InputText class="form-control" @bind-Value="model.Email1"></InputText>

            <ValidationMessage For="@(()=>model.Email1)"></ValidationMessage>
            <br />
        </div>

        <div class="col-12 mb-5">
            Name2:
            <InputText class="form-control" @bind-Value="model.Name2"></InputText>
            <br />
        </div>

        <div class="col-12 mb-5">
            Email2:
            <InputText class="form-control" @bind-Value="model.Email2"></InputText>

            <ValidationMessage For="@(()=>model.Email2)"></ValidationMessage>
            <br />
        </div>


        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" @onclick="() => PostAsync(formContext)">Save</button>

    </div>
    
</EditForm>

@code {
    private TestModel model;


    public Test()
    {
        model = new();

    }

    private void PostAsync(EditContext context)
    {
        bool formIsValid = context.Validate();
        if (formIsValid == false)
            return;

        Console.WriteLine("Data posted.");
    }

    public class TestModel
    {

        public string? Name1 { get; set; }

        [RequiredWhenOtherHasValue("Name1", ErrorMessage = "Email1 isequired with Name1")]
        public string? Email1 { get; set; }

        public string? Name2 { get; set; }

        [RequiredWhenOtherHasValue("Name2", ErrorMessage = "Email2 isequired with Name2")]
        public string? Email2 { get; set; }

    }
}
```

[image]

What can we do to trigger the red border of failed validation and show the error message under the text box?

Comment: This post helped me: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/17110

Comment: [Polite] Did it solve your problem?  If so create an answer.  It saves answerers (like me!) potentially wasting their time viewing and reading your question.

Answer (score 2):

Copied from https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/17110

This change resolved my problem:

```
- return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage ?? "Date selected must be greater or equal to today's date.");
+ return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage ?? "Date selected must be greater or equal to today's date.", new[] { validationContext.MemberName } );
```